# What is incorrect about this statement and/or proof?

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

If $f$ and $g$ are two functions of $x$ such that $f$ is differentiable with respect to $x$ at $h$, $g$ is continuous, and $h=g(a)$ for some $a$, then  $f$ is differentiable with respect to $g$.

Proof:

We are given that $$\lim _{x\rightarrow h} \frac{f(x)-f(h)}{x-h}=T$$ and $$\lim _{x\rightarrow a} g(x)=g(a)$$

Through this we can infer that for every $\varepsilon$ there exists a $\delta$ such that  $|\frac{f(x)-f(h)}{x-h}-T|<\varepsilon$ when $0<|x−h|<\delta$

Now we replace $x$ by $g(x)$ to get $\displaystyle \left|\frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)}-T\right|<\varepsilon$ when $0<|g(x)−g(a)|<\delta$

This implies that $$\lim _{g(x)\rightarrow g(a)} \frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)}=T$$

Now this is obviously untrue, but I can't seem to find where exactly I went wrong. I would really appreciate if someone could explain which step was incorrect.

Comment: How do you know that $0<|g(x)-g(a)|$ in general?

Comment: @RobertWolfe Thanks for pointing that out. It seems that it is incorrect. Just curious, is the statement at the beginning true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement "$f $is differentiable with respect to $g$" does not make sense because $ g$ is a function not an independent variable.

Also you are dividing by $ g(x)-g(a)$ which is not allowed unless it is not zero.

Comment: So what do we mean when we take the derivative of a function with respect to another function while using chain rule? Is it somehow different to what I did?

Comment: If you are trying to prove the chain rule, note that the derivatives are with respect to independent variables not with respect to functions. Please look at a real analysis book and see how the theorem is stated and proved.

Comment: Isn't $\frac{df(g(x))}{dx} = \frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)} \frac{dg(x)}{dx}$? So, what is the independent variable in $\frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)}$?

Comment: It is simply f'(g(x)) that is you take derivative of f(x) at x and then you replace x with g(x). It is a substitution. For example if you take derivative of sin(3x+1), you take derivative of sin(x) which is cos (x) and replace x with 3x+1 to get cos(3x+1) and multiply it with 3 which is derivative of 3x+1.